# regexp to remove entire paragraph based on it's content?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-parsing

hey guys,
I'm a regexp noob,
Is it possible with preg_replace to remove a the an entire paragraph tag?

```
<p><div class="vidwrapper"> lot of content with oder divs etc. </div><p>
```

The paragraph should only be removed if it is following div has a class of .vidwrapper.

Is that even possible? Any idea how this regexp would look like?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You _can_ do it with regex, but there will always be corner cases you cannot handle (at least, not within "reasonable" bounds). Take the following string where regex might chock on: `<p><div class="vidwrapper"> <!-- </p> --> lot of content with oder divs etc.</div><p>`. Trying to fix many of these little corner cases with a (or multiple) regex(-es) will most likely result in a hideous, error-prone and hard to maintain solution.

Comment: there will never be another <p> inside of it! It's always the same structure inside of this div! there are just other divs inside of it and a <script> tag!

Comment: shouldn't it be something like this: `$para = "/<p><div class='vidwrapper'>(.*?)<\/div><\/p>/smix";`

Comment: I could write the regex for you if I could understand what you are trying to do. Can you give some concrete examples of before and after?

Comment: well it's rather simple! I have a some complicated custom html that includes a youtube-player with a swfobject. This complicated html is in every post of my blog the same and is always wrapped inside this `<p><div class="vidwrapper>...`. However when it comes to RSS fees I don't want this youtube video to be visible and the vidwrapper around it makes no sense as well. So all I want todo actually is just get rid of this `<p><div class="vidwrapper>...` in every RSS-item. I'm found a already a regexp that would strip of just the script-tag inside of it (swf-object javascript) and that works fine!

Comment: However if I strip of the javascript inside there is also absolutely no need to have the empty wrapper and the <p> around it inside of my RSS feeds. I simply need to get rid of that! And there will be no need to make any exceptions or difficult special cases in this regex because the `<p><div class="vidwrapper>...` will always be the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a fixed occurrence, then following might work:

```
preg_replace('#<p>[^<]*<div[^>]+class="vidwrapper"[^>]*>.*?</p>#is', "")
```

For matching nested html you would normally need a recursing regex, hencewhy something like phpQuery or QueryPath is then often simpler:

```
$html = pq($html)->find("p div.vidwrapper")->parent()->remove()->html();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to do this using a regex, unless you know that there will be no paragraph (or anything that might superficially be interpreted as a paragraph) inside of the vidwrapper.

If you don't, writing a regex for something like this will be very hard:

```
<p><div class="vidwrapper"> Hello there. <p>Wee.</p> Yoink. </div></p>
```

```
<p><div class="vidwrapper"> Hello there. <!-- <p>Wee.</p> --> Yoink. </div></p>
```

An easier (and more robust) way would probably be to parse the HTML with an HTML parser, and do a search on the DOM tree instead.

#### See also:

- [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

If you think the script will cause problems, you can use this as well.

```
#
 \s*
 <p\s*> \s* <div \s+ class \s* = \s* (["']) vidwrapper \1 \s* >
 (?:
      <script (?:\s+ (?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+)? \s*>
      .*?
      </script\s*>)
   |  .
 )*?
 </p\s*>
#xs
```